# Someone knows the Area and Perimeter of the family of polar curves: r(a)= n + m*sin(a)^2.?

Tags: closed-form, area, polar-coordinates, curves

Someone knows the Area and Perimeter of the family of polar curve:

$$r(a)= n + m\cdot \sin^{2}(a)$$

Where $(n,m) \in R$.
And $a\in (0,2\pi)$

What I need is a closed-form on $(n,m)$.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematic SE. People here like to see your work. Please edit your post to include your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I dont find the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m$ and $n$ are such that $r(\phi):=n+m\sin^2\phi>0$ for all $\phi$ then you can use the following formula:
$${\rm enclosed\ area}={1\over2}\int_0^{2\pi}r^2(\phi)\>d\phi\ .$$
The result will of course be an expression containing the parameters $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Ok to to gets numbers. But not a closed on (n,m).

Comment: They looks like peanuts. The size is n and the family is m.

Comment: I need also the perimeter for any n,m.